# JTextComponent Update Synchronization

Tags: java

I have a `JEditorPane` and a `JList`. When the user selects an element in the `JList`, a website query is performed and the resulting `HTML` is written into the `JEditorPane`.

An issue arises however if the user scrolls through the `JList` **very quickly** since every change starts a new query and the `JEditorPane` gets updated in a possibly wrong order (individual results may take unpredictably longer or shorter to return) and cause de-sync for the current list selection and the `JEditorPane` meaning that a list selection now shows a wrong result.

Any ideas on how to ensure that this doesn't get screwed up?

I tried making the method for updating the `JEditorPane` `synchronized` (no effect), disabled the `JList` when a query has been launched (no effect) or paused the [`EDT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) using `Thread.sleep()` as long as a query went on (froze the gui). None of these solutions are satisfactory.

The gui needs to stay flexible yet never get de-synced like described above.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a really neat way that you can control the `JEditorPane`'s loading process, but for simplicity, I might consider using a `javax.swing.Timer`.

Basically, when the selection changes, you would start the (single run only) `Timer` configured to a short time (something like 250 milliseconds or so...as an example).

Each time the selection changes, the timer would be restarted, thus preventing the timer from trigger it's `ActionListener`...

Once the selection changes stop, the timer will be permitted to run it's course, triggering the `ActionListener` which would allow you to make a request to the `JEditorPane`

Have a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more ideas, just make sure you set it's `repeats` property to `false` ;)

Comment: Inside my `ListSelectionListener` I replaced the code with `timer.start()` and 250 milliseconds works fine for the task which is now inside the `actionListener` argument of the timer object.